# Is there a limit to the number of times you can multiclass?

Tags: dnd-4e, multi-classing

Is there a limit to the number of times you are able to multiclass, for example could you get 1 level in 4 different classes?

Comment: You can also check out **hybrid** characters (introduced in PHB3) which is more of a 50/50 multiclass option compared to the 90/10 feat based multiclassing of PHB1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. Page 208 of PHB notes:

> There are two restrictions on your choice of a class-specific multiclass feat. First, you can't take a multiclass feat for your own class. Second, once you take a multiclass feat, you can't take a class-specific feat for a different class. You can dabble in a second class, but not a third.

This is true for all classes except bard who have an explicit provision to take multiple class-specific feats:

[DDI:](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/class.aspx?id=104)

> MULTICLASS VERSATILITY
> You can choose class-specific multiclass feats from more than one class.

While the windrise ports background did allow multiple multiclass feats, the recent errata eliminated that option.

---

To address your specific confusion, there is no such thing as taking "levels" in other classes, only feats and power-swap feats. In essence, you are always your primary class (though with a multiclass feat you can take prestige paths and epic destinies and class-specific feats for your secondary class, as the feat indicates that you count as a member of that class for game purposes.)

Comment: So i can only have my first class, and then one multiclassed? I cant say, be a human starting as a rogue, multiclass into warrior, then take a level of sorcerer (assuming i meet all the class prereqs)?

Comment: No. There is no concept of "levels" in other classes in 4e. If you're a Human Rogue, you may take "student of the sword" to then count as a fighter for game purposes. If you're interested in getting more fighter powers, you then take power-swap feats to exchange a daily, a utility, and eventually an encounter from rogue to fighter.

Comment: oh, sorry I am still kind of stuck in dnd 3.5 mode, trying to get my brain around to the new system.

Comment: Some of the best advice anyone can receive while moving from 3E to 4E: forget everything you know about 3E. There are a lot of rules in 3E that are completely different in 4E, including everything from multiclassing to standing up from prone. Read the rules back to front, and don't let yourself make assumptions based on previous editions.

Comment: As noted, you can take the hybrid class (which is the approach most like the multiclassing of earlier editions, although in many ways its more like multiclassing in AD&D than 3.x) and this would give you aspects of two different classes.  If you then take one multiclass feat you could end up with aspects of three different classes.

Comment: Um... I /strongly/ disrecommend playing hybrids from my own experience. I've played one in a campaign and as a shammy/druid, should have been simple to play. The dissonance of two different roles is impossible to overstate.