# Can one multiclass into the same second class twice?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats, multi-classing

I know there is an answer similar to this at [Is there a limit to the number of times you can multiclass?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3624/is-there-a-limit-to-the-number-of-times-you-can-multiclass), but I want to know if one can multiclass twice in the same class. The rules seem weird to me; quoting from the `PHB`:

> There are two restrictions on your choice of a class-specific multiclass feat. First, you can't take a multiclass feat for your own class. Second, once you take a multiclass feat, you can't take a class-specific feat for a different class. You can dabble in a second class, but not a third.

So as an example, let's say I am a `Bladesinger` who took `Sneak of Shadows` for my multiclass `Rogue`.  Could I take `Ruthless Efficiency` in addition, if I qualified?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes**

Multiclass feats are restricted to a certain class, not to one and only one feat. While the evidence from the character builder suggests yes. There also seems to be nothing in the wording of multiclass restrictions to dispute this interpretation. There seem to be no contrary opinions on the forums, either.

Comment: Interesting.  I suppose it then becomes weird that technically, one could multiclass into Warlord many times getting practically every basic benefit for each Warlord type (Bravura, Resourceful, etc) while also being able to get an Inspiring warlord going.

Comment: It's also a complete waste of feats. The multiclass feats are not actually all that useful. But you cannot multiclass into your own class.

Comment: Perhaps it is a waste of feats, but if someone did it, its their choice.  Just wanted to see if its technically legal to do or not.  Thanks.  I'll give this question some more time though just in case.

Comment: @BrianBallsun-Stanton there are some MC feats that are decent on their own - the Barbarian MC granting daily +2 damage for an encounter, and the Heroes of the Feywild Battle Berserker Barbarian MC both add some nice extra oomph to a Slayer.

Comment: Also, I should probably clarify I meant an Inspiring Warlord with Inspiring Word, not an actual warlord for the class.  And yes Simon, that would be hella fantastic for a Slayer.

Answer (score 2):

I may be incorrect, but since taking a multi-class feat gives you *"that class"* for the purpose of feats and power-swap feats, I would assume that you can't take two `Rogue` multi-class feats because of the *"First, you can't take a multiclass feat for your own class"* wording.

Comment: I guess my confusion comes in more because of the "Monastic Adept" since its prerequisite is any monk multiclass feat, yet it falls under being a "Multiclass Monk" tag.  That is why it has me wondering if the "First, you can't take a multiclass feat for your own class" becomes weird if you take a feat that has the recursive need for a multiclass of the class.

Comment: @zapoqx even if this rule is correct, that feat is definitely ok. Looks like Brian has the right of it though...